# Set tab pane active on API settings?

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am trying to set a active tab on the basis of settings coming from API from angular function. tab is got activated after api call but tab pane is not got activated. here is my code :

**html**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-toggle="tabs">
                                    <!-- <li ng-show="settings.tabs.timeline" class="active" style="margin-bottom: -2px;"><a href="#timeline" onclick="tabMenu(this.id)" id="timelinetab" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Timeline"><i class="fa fa-history"></i></a></li> -->
   <li id = "inquiryli" ng-show="settings.tabs.inquiry" style="margin-bottom: -2px;"><a href="#inquiry" onclick="tabMenu(this.id)" id="inquirytab" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Inquiry"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a></li> 
   <li id = "packageli" ng-show="settings.tabs.packages" style="margin-bottom: -2px;"><a href="#package" onclick="tabMenu(this.id)" id="packagetab" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Packages"><i class="gi gi-snowflake"></i></a></li>
   <li id = "followupli" ng-show="settings.tabs.followups" style="margin-bottom: -2px;"><a href="#followup" onclick="tabMenu(this.id)"  id="followuptab" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Follow Ups"><i class="fa fa-recycle"></i></a></li>
   <li id = "invoiceli" ng-show="settings.tabs.invoices" style="margin-bottom: -2px;"><a href="#invoice" onclick="tabMenu(this.id)" id="invoicetab" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Invoices"><i class="gi gi-notes"></i></a></li>
   <li id = "paymentli" ng-show="settings.tabs.payments" style="margin-bottom: -2px;"><a href="#payment" onclick="tabMenu(this.id)" id="paymenttab" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Payments"><i class="fa fa-money"></i></a></li>
   <li id = "batchli" ng-show="settings.tabs.batches" style="margin-bottom: -2px;"><a href="#batch" onclick="tabMenu(this.id)" id="batchtab" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Batches"><i class="fa fa-cubes"></i></a></li>
   <li id = "attendanceli" ng-show="settings.tabs.attendance" style="margin-bottom: -2px;"><a href="#attendance" onclick="tabMenu(this.id)" id="attendancetab" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Attendance"><i class="gi gi-alarm"></i></a></li> 

</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="package"> ....content ...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="invoice"> ....content ...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="inquiry"> ....content ...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="followup"> ....content ...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="attendance"> ....content ...</div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('summaryController',function($scope,$http,$timeout,PagerService){

    $scope.settings = {};
    apiCall({"session_id":session_id,"user_id":user_id},"summaryRoute.php","selectUserConfig").then(function (response) { 
        if(response.data.error == 0){
            $scope.settings = response.data.data;
            if($scope.settings.user_type == 'M'){
                $("#packageli").addClass("active");
                $('.nav-tabs a[href="#package"]').tab('show')
            }
            else if($scope.settings.user_type == 'I'){
                $("#inquiryli").addClass("active");
                 $('.nav-tabs a[href="#inquiry"]').tab('show')
            }
            else{
                $("#followupli").addClass("active");
                $('.nav-tabs a[href="#followup"]').tab('show')
            }
        }
        else
           $scope.settings = {}; 

      console.log($scope.settings)
    });
});
```

Comment: It looks like you found the `active` class that makes the Tab "active" - did you try to do the same for the pane?

Comment: How would it be ? @MarkC.

Comment: Get rid of bootstrap.js and use angular-ui-bootstrap. There should be no jQuery or other dom code in a controller. Controllers should know anything about the view structure

Comment: but for a time I want some solution to solve this @charlietfl

Comment: And the proper solution is to use your data model to drive the view...that's how angular works. Your issue is trivial if you get rid of bootstrap.js

Comment: But angular is working with other elements which are in its scope. just this one got undone.

Comment: Please try to create  plunker for this.

Answer (score 0):

You have the values you need on your scope already. What you need to do is use ng-class, and there are several ways to do this. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

- using objects

  ```
  <li id = "packageli" ng-class="{ active: settings.user_type === 'M' }"></li>
  <li id = "inquiryli" ng-class="{ active: settings.user_type === 'I' }"></li>
  <li id = "followupli" ng-class="{ active: !(settings.user_type === 'I' || settings.user_type === 'M') }"></li>
  ```
- using a function, better because

  - logic is abstracted from view and isolated)
  - it can be reused with ng-show or any other directive
  - it can be reused to toggle other elements

html

```
<li id = "packageli" ng-class="{active: isPackageActive()}"></li>
<li id = "inquiryli" ng-class="{active: isInquiryActive()}"></li>
<li id = "followupli" ng-class="{active: isFollowUpActive()}"></li>
```

js

```
function isPackageActive() {
    return settings.user_type === 'M';
}

function isInquiryActive() {
    return settings.user_type === 'I';
}

function isFollowUpActive() {
    return !(isInquiryActive() || isPackageActive());
}
```

**PS:** Don't use jquery in your controller. If you need to do something you cant do with angular directives like ng-model, ng-class etc use a custom directive